# how to resolve not enough resources: open_files error

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

```
file_in_directory(File):-
  working_directory(D,D),
  directory_files(D,Entries),
  member(File,Entries).

tree_file_in_directory(File):-
  file_in_directory(File),
  atom_codes('.treeliker',TreeLikerCodes),
  atom_codes(File, FileCode),
  append(_FileStripped,TreeLikerCode,FileCode).

run_tree_liker(File):-
   process_create(path(java), 
   ['-Xmx8gb','-cp', 'TreeLiker.jar', 'ida.ilp.treeLiker.TreeLikerMain','-batch', File], [stdout(pipe(Out)), process(PID)]).

forall(
   tree_file_in_directory(File),
   (
   run_tree_liker(File),
   run_weka(File, Lines)
   )
).
```

I have a program like this where `run_tree_liker/1` and `run_weka/2` use `process_create/3` to run a java jar program. The first program creates an .arff file for each .treeliker file in the directory. The run weka part then uses the .arff file and asserts some facts to the database.

There are about 1400 .treeliker files in the directory and the program runs, but it always cuts out after about 400 with an `Error: Not enough resources: open_files` . How can I get the program to open one file at a time and close the file once the process has completed so that this error does not occur?

Comment: I guess from the code, that closing the files is the job for the programs that open them, i.e. your java programs.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to provide an answer since it's unclear where all the places are that you might be opening and not closing files. But as @EugeneSh. says, if you're calling Java code that is creating files, those modules need also to close them in a timely fashion.

Comment: The java programs are just simple jar files that I would normally call from the command line with out a problem.. wouldnt java throw an error if that was a case rather than prolog?

Comment: So who is opening the files?

Comment: The java programs. The first program is this: http://ida.felk.cvut.cz/treeliker/TreeLiker.html 
http://ida.felk.cvut.cz/treeliker/download/treeliker.pdf
ill add the calling code..

Comment: The run_weka  program is a simple java program made into a jar based on this code: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/a-simple-machine-learning-example-in-java/

Comment: Does it work if you include the `process_create` option, `detach(false)`?

Comment: I tried using `detached(false)` and it still cuts out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use setup_call_cleanup/3 and close/1

```
run_jar(Jar,Option,Lines):-
   setup_call_cleanup(
   process_create(path(java),['-jar',Jar,Option],[stdout(pipe(Out))]),
   read_lines(Out,Lines),
   close(Out)).
```

Thanks to Jan on the mailing list.